# PHPUnit - Symfony authorization with x-api-key

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, authorization, symfony4

I am using PHPUnit test to write functional test for specific endpoint.

Problem with it is that for the authorization process I have to set `X-API-KEY` in headers section of the request.

I keep getting an error:

> Authentication Required

I am using an valid api key form my test database table and it return this specific error I mentioned above.

```
 public function testDoItSuccessful()
{
    $client = static::createClient(
        [],
        ['HTTP_x-api-key' => 'clWD0ggquG1Ok2xOVLIcMmPJtu1uYWG']
    );

    $client->request(
        Request::METHOD_POST,
        '/api/v1/do-it',
        [],
        [],
        [
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
            'ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
        ],
        json_encode($myArray)
    );

   return $client;
 }
```

As I am new, primarily with authorization process in test env any help is highly appreciated.

*Note:* I am using Symfony `4.4`

I tried [THIS](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2017/05/08/setting-http-headers-in-symfony-crawler-client/).

Error is coming for these two functions in `TokenAuthenticator` class.

```
public function supports(Request $request)
{
    $hasApiKey = true;
    $requestHeaders = $this->getLowerCasedHeaders();
    if (!isset($requestHeaders['x-api-key'])) {
        $hasApiKey = false;
    }
    return $hasApiKey;
}

private function getLowerCasedHeaders()
{
    $requestHeaders = getallheaders();
    return array_change_key_case($requestHeaders, CASE_LOWER);
}


public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $requestHeaders = $this->getLowerCasedHeaders();
    return $requestHeaders['x-api-key'];
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    if (null === $credentials) {
        // Code 401 "Unauthorized"
        return null;
    }

    return $this->entityManager->getRepository(Client::class)->findOneBy(['apiKey' => $credentials]);
}

public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    if ($user->getStatus() != Client::STATUS_ACTIVE) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("USER_NOT_ACTIVE", 403);
    }
    $user->setLastSeen(new DateTime('now'));
    $this->entityManager->persist($user);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    return true;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    return null;
}

public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $data = [
        'message' => 'Authentication failed, wrong api key'
    ];
    if ($exception->getCode() == 403) {
        $data = ['message' => $exception->getMessage()];
    }

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}

public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
{
    $data = [
        // you might translate this message
        'message' => 'Authentication Required'
    ];

    return new JsonResponse($data, Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
}

public function supportsRememberMe()
{
    return false;
}
```

I have changed `apache_request_headers()` to `getallheaders()` and tests are passing with `Authentication Required` message.

When `print_r()` the:

```
$requestHeaders = $this->getLowerCasedHeaders();
```

I can not see my defined headers from request? It returns `Array()`..

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how the Client Class parse the headers, specially on the test, there  is a part where the code execute a search for the word HTTP_ for the custom header. So basically on your test instead of call only x-api-key you need to add the prefix HTTP_. Try with this:

TokenAuthenticator

```php
public function supports(Request $request)
{
    return $request->headers->has('x-api-key');
}
```

On your test:

```php
public function testDoItSuccessful()
{
     crawler = $this->client->request(
         Request::METHOD_POST,
         '/api/v1/do-it',
         [],
         [],
         ['HTTP_x-api-key' => self::TOKEN, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json', 'ACCEPT' => 'application/json']
     );
     $status = $this->client->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: This works, but i am getting 401 (Authentication Required) error? @RicardoJesusRuiz

Comment: in this case, maybe the Authenticator class needs more changes, could you update the question?

Comment: I updated the issue. Please check. @RicardoJesusRuiz

Comment: in this case @misafe, I want to see the rest of the Authenticator class, why? because in some part of the code is throwing an exception or not returning the correct values. You can check the next video https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-security/api-token-authenticator

Comment: I understand. I posted entire class. Thanks a lot for your help. @RicardoJesusRuiz

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is to return a UserInterface with the role defined in your security:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_API }
```

My firewall:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        custom_authenticators:
            - App\CrediFastCore\Infrastructure\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
```

Since we need ROLE_API

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
{
    $apiToken = $request->headers->get('X-AUTH-TOKEN');

    if (null === $apiToken) {
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('No API token provided');
    }

    if ($this->parameters->get('api_key') != $apiToken) {
        //I compare api token with the one I've set on my parameters.yaml
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Wrong API token provided');
    }

    $user = new User();
    $user->setName('api');
    $user->setRoles(['ROLE_API']);

    return new SelfValidatingPassport(
        new UserBadge($apiToken, function () use ($user, $apiToken) {
            return $user;
        })
    );
}
```

This part was the "fix"

```
return new SelfValidatingPassport(
        new UserBadge($apiToken, function () use ($user, $apiToken) {
            return $user;
        })
    );
```